# Can't loop array passed to component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, gatsby

Hello dear Stack Overflow, I just started a Gatsby website but I'm having issues looping through an array passed to a component.

### What I'm trying to do:

I have a Gatsby page called blog.js, in this page I have been showing blog titles retrived via GraphQL. Using a loop directly in the blog.js page I can see all the titles.

My loop inside of blog.js looks like this

```js
      <div> 
            <h1>Blogg data</h1>
            {data.posts.edges.map (({ node }) => (
                <p>{node.title}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
```

It retrieves data from the following GraphQL query

```js
export const query = graphql`
  query BlogPageQuery {
    posts: allSanityPost(
      limit: 12
      sort: { fields: [publishedAt], order: DESC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          publishedAt
          mainImage {
            asset {
              _id
            }
            alt
          }
          title
          _rawExcerpt
          slug {
            current
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Instead of creating the blog posts previews in blog.js I instead want to use a component to do this. I've created a component called  BlogPostPreviewGrid and call it like this from blog.js

```js
<BlogPostPreviewGrid blogPosts={data}/>
```

My BlogPostPreviewGrid component currently looks like this

```js
const BlogPostPreviewGrid = blogPosts => {
    return (
    <div>   
     <p>Here be component data</p>

  {console.log(blogPosts)}
     {blogPosts.posts.edges.map (({ node }) => (
                <p>{node.title}</p>
            ))}
    </div>
    )

}
export default BlogPostPreviewGrid
```

### What's not working:

I cannot loop through the data retrieved by the component, when running the loop I get a console error massage stating `blogPostPreviewGrid.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined`

### What have I tried:

My first response was to console.log blogPosts, console.log shows the array object, I've attached a the array from Chromes console log

```
blogPostPreviewGrid.js:13 {blogPosts: {…}}blogPosts: posts: edges: Array(2)0: node: {id: "54fe241a-c7d4-50d2-be51-4403304ddc86", publishedAt: "2020-01-05T23:00:00.000Z", mainImage: {…}, title: "Testpost2", _rawExcerpt: Array(1), …}__proto__: Object1: {node: {…}}length:
```

I've also written a conditional statement so that the component only tries to render the data if something exists in blogPosts and tried tweak the loop. I ended up with doing a git reset --hard so the conditional rendering is not present right now.

Thank you for all replies!

Comment: What library do you use for graphq? it probably has some API to render components only after data is loaded. Anyways, conditional rendering should have helped, you probably made a mistake in the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values passed to children components in react are passed in one big object known as `props`: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html.

So you need to either destructure props in your function call:

```
const BlogPostPreviewGrid = ({blogPosts}) => {
    // do stuff
    console.log(blogPosts)
}
```

Or use props object

```
const BlogPostPreviewGrid = props => {
    // do stuff using blogPosts 
    console.log(props.blogPosts);
}
```

If your component looked something like this `<Foo prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} />` then you would access it like so:

```
const Foo = props => {
    console.log(props.prop1);
    console.log(props.prop2);
}
```

or like so:

```
const Foo = ({ prop1, prop2 }) => {
    console.log(prop1);
    console.log(prop2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

**BlogPostPreviewGrid.jsx**

```
const BlogPostPreviewGrid = ({blogPosts}) => {
    return (
      <div>
         {blogPosts.posts.edges.map (({ node }) => (
            <p>{node.title}</p>
         ))}
      </div>
    )

}
export default BlogPostPreviewGrid
```